# Does the outcome depend on the phase arbitrariness in the definition of the eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, observables

Imagine you have a Hamiltonian that is a real symmetric matrix in some basis. From general theory we know that the eigenvalues $E_n$ are real but also eigenvectors can be chosen purely real $|n\rangle$. I calculate the following quantity (which is not zero):

$$\langle m | O|n\rangle + \langle n | O | m \rangle $$

for some hermitian operator $O$ the above quantity is purely real:

$$2\text {Re}\{\langle n | O | m \rangle\}$$

Now the problem I have is the arbitrariness of the phase factor in the definition of the eigenvectors. I can also use eigenstates with phase in front:

$$e^{i\varphi_{n}}|n\rangle$$

But then the quantity changes due to difference of phase factors. How is it possible? I was always taught in a course of quantum mechanics that we don't care about the phase and yet I get different results.

Answer (score 1):

You've just proven that the quantity
$$
\langle m|O|n\rangle+ \langle n|O|m\rangle
$$
is not an observable quantity, or even "real", since it's representation dependent. This shouldn't bother you; plenty of quantities in physics are representation dependent. For example, "distance to the origin" is not a real quantity in classical mechanics, since it depends on where you put your coordinate axis; "value of the voltage" is not a real quantity since it depends on where you set $V=0$, "the vector potential" is not a real quantity since it depends on your gauge, etc. This is just one more quantity that is not "real" in the same sense. You might use it in some intermediate step to solving a physical problem, but by the end of the problem you should be left with quantities that are "real", i.e. not representation dependent.

Comment: Thank you @Jahan ! I have a quick question. I have some pure quantum state $|\psi\rangle = \alpha |0\rangle  + \beta|1\rangle$ and I redefine eigenstates $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ by multiplying them by some different phase factors $e^{i\varphi_{0,1}}$. Is the new state different than the initial one? Are we able to measure relative phase between eigenstates forming the quantum state or just an amplitude?

Comment: If you change the phases of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, then the state you wrote down would be different. The "relative phase" between different states isn't really well-defined, since the thing you define to be "the eigenstate" is arbitrary up to a phase to begin with. However, once you're more comfortable with QM, look up "Berry Connection"; this is one way to define relative phases between different eigenstates in a way that has measurable consequences.